# Cannot resolve a variable of same class but inside a static method

Tags: java, class, static

My Problem: "return ipAddr"
ipAddr cannot be resolved to a variable. 
So, is this because the method is static??

```
package oop.address;

    import java.net.InetAddress;

    public class address {

        public static  address createIP(String ip) {

            try {
                InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Fehler");
            }

                return null;
        }

         public  InetAddress get_ipAddr(){

            return ipAddr;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, is this because the method is static??

No the fact that the method is static has nothing to do with it. The problem is that `ipAddr` is created in `createIP()`, and thus only exists in the scope of the method. I believe you wanted to make it a class variable:

```
private static InetAddress ipAddr;

public static  address createIP(String ip) {
     try {
         ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Fehler");
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: won't work: ipAddr is an instance variable whereas the method is static. non-static members can't be accessed from static methods.

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin You are correct. I edited my answer

Comment: why not just moving variable declaration out of the try scope?:)

Answer (score 0):

Every `{}` pair will create a custom scope with it's own "lifetime", which in the case of nested blocks in a method body will be always shorter than the outer scope.

Easy fix is:

```
public static  address createIP(String ip) {
    InetAddress ipAddr = null;
    try {
        ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fehler");
    }
    return ipAddr;
}
```

But if you want to eliminate `null`, you have to either throw exception to the next stack frame (or you can just not to catch it) or specify a default value in the case of exception.

Comment: I believe the OP was also talking about their `get_ipAddr()` method

Comment: @GBlodgett "My Problem: "return ipAddr" ipAddr cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: That line only appears in the `get_ipAddr()` method in OP's code